# what went wrong in my Excel if else formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have written a IF formula with Vlookup. Vookup is working perfectly fine. But the else part is not working.
The idea is simple A3 content of the current sheet is = that in first sheet...then substitute 2 (give 2 marks). Else give value 0 (zero).
I have attached the sheet for your kind reference.
I even checked the format of the current cell (the cell for which I am writing the formula). And it is number. But still zero (0) is not substituted.
Could you please guide me as what went wrong? What is the correct formula?
=IF(A3=VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$51,1,0), 2, 0)
Please help
Thanks

Comment: For reference, you may check this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `A3` content exists in range `Sheet1!$A$3:$A$51`.

Your `VLOOKUP` returns an error if the value cannot be found (`#N/A`) and every operation with this result will return `#N/A`.

Change your function to:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$A$3:$A$51,1,0)), 0, 2)
```

Unless you are trying to do something different than check if A3 is in that range.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its very kind of you to give me the solution. May God bless you. Stay safe.